# In TeamCity, how do you verify a system/environment variable has been set?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, continuous-integration, environment-variables, teamcity

Other than observing that it's obviously not set because it doesn't work.  ;)

I have been going through the TC documentation for 9.1 and cannot find anything that allows me to output system properties or environment variables to its log.  I have checked in the Verbose and raw build log file.

My Visual Studio 2008 environment is set to use third party libraries like boost, and I have the include and lib directories set to include $(THIRDPARTY)..., so I first added an environment variable in Build Parameters called env.THIRDPARTY and pointed it to the proper folder.  However, the build fails because it can't find the files.

I then tried using a system parameter, with the same outcome.

I then thought I was being smart by adding a pre-build event to my project and confirming that it was output to the VS build window.  Unfortunately, the TeamCity build log doesn't include all of those messages.

So I have two questions:
1. How do I confirm what TeamCity is using for env.THIRDPARTY? (it's most likely empty)
2. What am I missing with the environment variable?  I have used this many times in the past with VS2010 and VS2013 solutions and have never had a problem.  My current build workflow for another product depends on this for injecting SVN revision info, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a command line build step that simply does echo "%variable_name%", preceded with "system." or "env." as needed. Then you can find that line in the build log.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not being specific enough in my question.  I was looking for a way to see what TeamCity is doing internally so I could verify that it is trying to use the environment variable that I had created in my build configuration.  I already had echo statements in my csproj properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one solution I tried that helped me figure out the problem.

Add the /fileLogger switch to MSBuild so that an msbuild.log file is generated.  You can then add this as an artifact, or just open the file directly and peruse its contents.